# Which combinations of CAP does GdH support?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, distributed-computing

I'm interested in the implementation of GdH (Glasgow Distributed Haskell).
However, I could not find out which combinations in CAP theorem GdH supports.
Can we choose one of them or do programs in GdH consist of explicit processes like Erlang?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read it's essentially RMI only you're communicating using Mvars, there in my experience aren't really any limitations that any ecosystem for CAP, so much as in the problems in themselves for example YOU can use more than 5 nodes in ETCD or Zookeeper, but all of the election messages, the fact that the leader commits to all nodes, the request forwarding, the checks you have to make before applying the log, doesn't exactly make it performant well does it.

Nobody should be using RMI for a new application in 2017,honestly you would be better off using an RPC package.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/courier which is a light weight message passing lib, Zeromq, and Best for last

http://haskell-distributed.github.io/  which is basically the closest thing you get to OTP on haskell.